# Failure of Schur's lemma for topological group representations

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

Is there an example of $G$, $\rho$ as below?

- $G$ is a locally compact group.
- $\rho$ is a continuous representation of $G$ on a Hilbert space $V$. This means that we have a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of bounded linear operators on $V$ with bounded inverse, such that $G \times V \rightarrow V$ is continuous.
- Schur's lemma fails for $\rho$.